# Crosscompile qt6 for raspberry pi 4

Tags: qt, cross-compiling, raspberry-pi4, qt6

I have read this qt6 [doc](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/configure-linux-device.html), so I start to play with this, but maybe the docs leaks some infos and the configure step fails quickly with this error:

```
CMake Error at cmake/QtBaseConfigureTests.cmake:21 (message):
  Failed to compile architecture detection file.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/QtBaseConfigureTests.cmake:120 (qt_run_config_test_architecture)
  cmake/QtBaseConfigureTests.cmake:133 (qt_run_qtbase_config_tests)
  CMakeLists.txt:68 (include)
```

My cmake command is here:

```
'/usr/local/bin/cmake' '-DQT_HOST_PATH=/opt/qt6/6.0.1/gcc_64' '-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/mattia/raspi4-qt6/qt-cross/toolchain.cmake' '-DQT_BUILD_TOOLS_WHEN_CROSSCOMPILING=ON' '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/qt_v6.0.1' '-DCMAKE_STAGING_PREFIX=/home/mattia/raspi4-qt6/build/qt_v6.0.1' '-DQT_BUILD_EXAMPLES=FALSE' '-DQT_BUILD_TESTS=FALSE' '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release' '-DINPUT_opengl=es2' '-DINPUT_eglfs=ON' '-G' 'Ninja' '/home/mattia/raspi4-qt6/src/qtbase
```

While mine toolchaine.cmake is here:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)
include_guard(GLOBAL)

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR armv8)

set(TARGET_SYSROOT /home/mattia/raspi4-qt6/sysroot)
set(CROSS_COMPILER /home/mattia/raspi4-qt6/tools/cross-pi-gcc-10.2.0-2/bin)

set(CMAKE_SYSROOT ${TARGET_SYSROOT})


set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${CROSS_COMPILER}/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${CROSS_COMPILER}/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++)
set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH} "")
set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR} ${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/usr/lib/arm-gnueabihf/pkgconfig:${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/usr/share/pkgconfig)
set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR} ${CMAKE_SYSROOT})


set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc you linked worked properly for me. I added some more notes here: https://bugfreeblog.duckdns.org/2021/09/qt-6-on-raspberry-pi-on-eglfs.html. Maybe you can try with the toolchain I linked in the article.

Comment: Hi Luca,
thank you for your work with #PiOmx, I really liked it. When I wrote this question, Qt6 was in early state of deploy and QtMultimedia was not available. I'll read your blog to know your impressions about use QtMultimedia to play video without use VLC or at least omxplayer.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you are using Cygwin. I had same problem with cygwin, because ARM compiler not understand cygwin path `/cygdrive/d/cygwin/home.....`

For crosscompile qt6 on windows host use windows cmake and windows CMD. Cygwin is not needed..

Comment: I was on linux, but compile qt6 now is useless without some key modules.